# Equation of a Plane from Picture

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Picture of the Plane]

I understand the formula is $ax + by + cz + d$ but don't know how to interpret that from the image.

Comment: What do you mean you "understand" that the formula is $ax + by + cz + d$ - what exactly do you understand regarding this formula?

Comment: The points $(x,y,z)$ on the plane are supposed to satisfy $ax+by+cz+d=0$. In particular the picture gives you three points $(3,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$, and $(0,0,5)$. Put these into the equation and that gives you $3$ equations that $a,b,c,d$ should satisfy. Observe that $(0,0,0)$ should not on the plane, therefore $d\neq0$. You can assume $d=1$. That gives you one more equation, which together with the other three allow you to uniquely determine $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get you started. Say your plane is defined by the equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$. Then we know that the points $P=(0,0,5),~Q=(0,2,0),~R=(3,0,0)$ are on this plane. Hence, we get the system of equations
$$\begin{cases}a(0)+b(0)+c(5)+d=0\\a(0)+b(2)+c(0)+d=0\\a(3)+b(0)+c(0)+d=0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

There's a formula, when the axes-intercepts $(a,0,0),\: (0,b,0),\: (0,0,c)$ are given, that every well-bred people should know:
$$\frac xa+\frac yb+\frac zc=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

For something like that problem the intercept from of the plane equation would be the quickest way to find the equation. https://www.ditutor.com/space/intercept_equation.html